# "How to answer" help page doesn't mention anything about commentary in answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, help-center

Today I encountered an answer that was prefaced with a questionnaire to the OP. Something like *"I'm not sure I understand what you mean..."* and a few questions asking to clarify the question.

To my surprise, the [*how to answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) help article doesn't mention anything about this or give any guidance to new users that this is wrong.

The ***Pay it forward*** paragraph mentions that a thank-you answer is not OK.
There is also the ***Answer well-asked questions*** paragraph which is fine, but it doesn't mention anything about not asking for clarifications in the answer itself.

While it might look obvious to seasoned community members, it is surely not so for new users. This is evident by the fact that the aforementioned user reacted with *"duly noted. Didn't know about this"* when I told them in a comment that questions to the OP should go in comments and not in the answer.

I would like to see a paragraph (or maybe part of the ***Answer the question*** one) about commentary in answers in that help article. Something along the lines of:

> Don't address the author of the question <sup>[new users might not be familiar with OP]</sup> or write conversational
> comments. Your answer should directly answer the question. If you have
> any questions or need clarifications, you can use comments under the
> question (if you have over 50 rep).

I know, I know what you're thinking and I already agree - *"Even if that text would be there, what makes you think that user even bothered to read that page?"*. But I was going to link to the help article in a comment when I thought to check if that is actually mentioned there.

Comment: It could also maybe be clearer about not writing "I'm having the same problem" in there, judging by the number of those I delete every day.  On the other hand, I suspect approximately none of them have read the *How to Answer* page.

Comment: @RyanM I agree with both arguments. Regarding the first: the only NAA-related guidance is about thank-you and link-only (in a way...). It should definitely be clearer to all other kinds of NAA (there actually is a paragraph about ***Have the same problem?*** which actually encourages to post partial answers...). Regarding the second, as I said I'm sure most users don't read the page. But I want to believe that at least some will bother to have a quick look if someone directly links them to it...

Comment: Oh, definitely don't interpret what I said as an argument against this: I'm all for it.

Comment: Just to clarify, is this about an answer that is actually NAA, or only including personal thought like "*I'm not sure I understand what you mean...*" but then explains what the answer in detail. While the former is certainly wrong, the latter is debatable, though it might still be removable as fluff.

Comment: @AndrewT. To clarify (please let me know if this should be edited in the question), the answer prefaced with *"I'm not sure"* and a few questions, and then went on with something like *"Anyway you should do..."* and an attempt of an answer based on what the user understood the question was. I eventually edited out the preface with the questions (the user had enough rep to comment anyway) and left the attempt and commented on the answer as I mentioned above

Comment: I see. I sometimes noticed <50 rep users doing that, both asking for clarification + attempting at answering in the same answer, but rarely for higher rep.

Comment: Some questions are not 100 Prozent clear and leave much room for interpretation . So you give an more generic answer , in which you explain your point of view and hope that the user gets help or clarifies things up so a almost normal ptocedure

Comment: @nbk Well that is not (shouldn't be...) a normal procedure. If a question is not clear, you should ask for clarifications in comments and answer once you understand it. Anyway, an answer is not the place to ask for clarifications. You can post a speculative answer and ask for clarifications in comments, but don't ask for clarifications in an answer...

Comment: Yes, user onboarding is not great. There isn't any prevention of the most common pitfalls (causing a lot of *unnecessary and preventable* pain in the process). A canonical is *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Comment: @Tomerikoo as as for a long working programmer like me, knows a lot of problems and solutions. So that my brain recognizes a solution for the problem like I understand it. That may not be the solution that user is looking for, so the user adds som es more clarification and I adapt my answer. The answer I am often helpful, because the asker can use it to clarify and that couldn't be done on a comment. So maybe you are looked ng only for questions that are perfectly clear, but I like chalanges and use the comment quite often fo RR clarification, but can't be done in a camment

Comment: @nbk ok I don't have a problem with people posting answers when the question is not clear. I might not agree with it, but there is nothing we can do to stop it and I can understand your approach. My problem presented here was that the user asked for clarifications ***inside*** the answer (they had enough rep to comment), not the fact that they answered (sorry if that wasn't clear in my post)